# Get column value for last 3 years in single select statement (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

let's say I have the table below:

| id | user_id | level | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2019-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 2021-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z |

Let's say I want to get a user's `level` for each of the last 3 years, based on date created, in a single row.

Something like:

```
SELECT user_id, (some query here) AS "level_2019"
      , (some query here) AS "level_2020", (some query here) AS "level_2021"  
FROM table
```

Is this something that's possible for a single select statement? I'd also like the level for that year to be null if they don't have one for that year.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the dynamic aliases you need dynamuc sql for such a query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `level` INTEGER,
>   `date_created` varchaR(24)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `user_id`, `level`, `date_created`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '2', '2019-07-01T18:53:41.000Z'),
>   ('2', '1', '3', '2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z'),
>   ('3', '1', '4', '2021-07-01T18:53:41.000Z'),
>   ('4', '2', '2', '2020-07-01T18:53:41.000Z');
> ```

> ```
> SET @column_alias1 := CONCAT('level_',YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 Year));
> SET @column_alias2 := CONCAT('level_',YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 Year));
> SET @column_alias3 := CONCAT('level_',YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 Year));
> SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT `user_id`,
> MIN( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = YEAR( NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR), `level`,NULL)) as `', @column_alias1, '` 
> ,MIN( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = YEAR( NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR), `level`,NULL)) as `', @column_alias2, '`
> ,MIN( IF (YEAR(CAST(`date_created` AS DATETIME)) = YEAR( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR), `level`,NULL)) as `', @column_alias3, '`
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `user_id`');
> PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
> EXECUTE dynamic_statement
> ```

> ```
> user_id | level_2019 | level_2020 | level_2021
> ------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
>       1 |          2 |          3 |          4
>       2 |       null |          2 |       null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49f05a0d78038ceb6955c42dd0def591)*

Comment: ok thank you! if i were able to use static aliases, say the years I need are 2019,2020,2021, would that be attainable without dynamic sql?

Comment: think i answered my own question, sorry! this is perfect. thank you.

Comment: if there were two levels that were set in the same year, and I used MAX instead of MIN there, would it get the highest level from that year? I'd assume yes unless I'm missing something.

Comment: yes without the dynbamic aliases ypou don't need the dynamic sql. if you have more than one level you need much more code like a rownumber and a outer sql